# store multiple radio groups status android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I am working on an app which have multiple Radio Groups.
I want to save their checked status and restore it on next restart.

So which is be the most efficient way to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values

Comment: @BradBrown My Question is how to store "multiple Radio group". And yours is just about sharedprefrence.

Comment: If you want to save and restore information that is done either with a database or with a shared preference. You would parse out the values and store them accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use SharedPreferences to store the checked items in the radio groups because they will be present unless we uninstall the app.

To store value's in shared preferences

```
List<RadioGroup> radioGroups;
List<String> savedids;

SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("number of radio groups", radiogroupsCount);
for(int i=0; i< radiogroupsCount; i++){
editor.putString("radioGroup"+String.valueOf(i), radioButtonGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId(););
}
editor.commit();();
```

To retrieve values from shared preferences:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
 String count = preferences.getString("number of radio groups", 0);
if(count >=0){
for(int i=0; i < count; i++){
 savedIds.add(preferences.getString("radioGroup"+String.valueOf(i),""));
  }
 }
```

Comment: Yes but how will I use sharedprefrence to store multiple status of different radio group in same activity.

Comment: I want to store multiple status in same sharedpreference, so how will i store it?